# LinkedList parameters in Java

Tags: java, list, linked-list

I created a program that contains linked lists that are passed various methods. While this works just fine in Java... a style checker program we have to use doesn't like it

It says: Declaring variables, return values or parameters of
 type 'LinkedList' is not allowed.

If I declare them as simply List then I don't have access to the methods I want. What should I do?

Comment: What methods of `LinkedList` do you use that aren't in `List`?

Comment: What style checker program are you using? Are you sure that the problem is not that they are not with generics arguments?

Comment: It's going to be hard to answer this question without seeing at least part of the code, knowing which type of checker program you use and what you use it for. Please try to be more specific (more data rarely hurts)

Comment: ignore the style checker, or tell the style checker developers that LinkedList has unique methods (addFirst,addLast, etc) that are commonly used, and should not be flagged.

Answer (score 4):

Either declare it as [`Deque`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) (the other interface it implements) or reconfigure the style checker program. The `Deque` has however some missing methods as opposed to [`List`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html). Here's an extract from its Javadoc:

> Unlike the `List` interface, this interface does not provide support for indexed access to elements.

But I don't expect that you're using them :)

Answer (score -1):

If you are sure, the value which enters in to Style Checker Program is an LinkedList then cast the List to LinkedList which gives access to your methods.

Comment: The style checker isn't going to like that cast either.